# Backup a Minecraft server that isn't mine

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

Is there any way to get a backup of a Minecraft server that isn't mine?
I would like to know so I can test things without having to go on the server and use my resources.

Comment: No. There's a reason why getting the seed requires admin rights: Some things might be supposed to stay secret.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that, you would have to be and Admin. But if you want to test something; just create a Minecraft world in creative mode and test in there.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this but I have zero experience using it personally ;)

https://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding-java-edition/minecraft-mods/2520465-1-12-2-1-11-2-1-10-2-1-8-9-world-downloader-mod

I hope it helps...